# How to align the bottom of a UIView with the bottom of the screen always

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, interface-builder

I want a background image to always be aligned with the bottom of the screen regardless of screen size, iOS Version, or Personal Hotspot messages etc. But none of the interface builder alignment options seem to work in every case.

I have 2 different sized images to fit 3.5' and 4' retina which change via code but their alignment is always thrown off by 'Personal Hotspot' and other messages changing the size of the parent view.

My images are the size of the screen and should fill the whole screen always. There is a black area where tab bar and status bar will overlay.

There are buttons aligned with the background and everything gets thrown out by messages that resize the parent view.

I want the bottom of the UIImageView to be aligned with the bottom of the screen always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried the contentMode property?

```
theImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeBottom;
```

There is also a menu item for this in interface builder if you prefer to set it there.

then if you are using auto layout, simply add a bottom space constraint from your image view to the bottom layout guide.

If you're not using auto layout, a fixed bottom margin on the autoresizing mask should do the trick.

Comment: Ok I'd tried that before but the image was being scaled up a crazy amount. Problem was I hadn't made separate @2x versions of the images so when scaling was off it was displaying the retina images on non-retina preview.